# How can there still be apps like Social Blade that get so much information about Instagram accounts when the Instagram API is so restricted?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

You can find a lot of apps on the app store that show you who's blocked you, your followers list, etc.. But how come? The Instagram Basic Display API and even the Instagram GRAPH API are so limited nowadays. I can't find a way to get someone's followers list.

Answer (score 1):

I now know that all of that information is aquired through Web Scraping. 
Source: https://socialblade.com/blog/channels-track/